# Convert int to list in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

I would like to convert a data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame({id:[1, 2, 3]})
```

to

```
res = pd.DataFrame({id:[[1], [2], [3]]})
```

i.e convert each element in the cell to a Python list.

However I tried

```
res = d.apply(lambda row: [row.id], axis=1)
```

it returned a dataframe containing types of below instead of type list:

```
<bound method Series.item of item 2\nName: ..
```

so how can I get the list type of elements in the cell instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
d['id'] = d['id'].apply(lambda x: [x])
d
#   id
#0  [1]
#1  [2]
#2  [3]
```

Or use `apply` directly on data frame:

```
d.apply(lambda r: [[r.id]], axis=1)

#id
#0  [1]
#1  [2]
#2  [3]
```

*Data*:

```
d = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2, 3]})         # notice the quote around id
```

Comment: I believe that the the OP needs to put *id* in quotes for it to register as a column name in their first creation of the DataFrame

Comment: @ivan7707 You are right. I corrected that part and thought it might be a typo from OP.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large dataframe, it might be wise to avoid an `apply`. Try:

```
pd.Series(d.values.reshape(-1, 1).tolist()).to_frame(name=d.columns[0])
    id
0  [1]
1  [2]
2  [3]
```

---

**Performance**

```
d.shape
(1000000, 1)
```

```
1 loop, best of 3: 444 ms per loop  # psidom
```

```
1 loop, best of 3: 304 ms per loop  # coldspeed
```

Comment: thanks for the info, right now performance is not an issue, so i'll use the simple form for now.